# Display Column Grid With Both Checkboxes and labels so that checkboxes are clickable and sendable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, extjs4.2

I would like to display in one grid checkboxes and data labels so that labels are readonly and checkboxes are clickable and their result is sendable to the PHP backend. The purpose of this window would be to associate some articles from an order with pictures labels.

```
EXT JS with Ext.grid.ColumnModel: 
setCM : function(){
        var checkColumn = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
               header: 'Choix',
               dataIndex: 'NOM_LOGO',
               align : 'center',
               width: 50
            });

        // add the column to the column model
        this.cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
               checkColumn,
               {
                   header: 'Nom Logo',
                   dataIndex: 'NOM_LOGO'
               }
        ]);
    },
EXT JS without Ext.grid.ColumnModel and with renderer:
    setCM : function(){
        this.cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            columns: [         
                 {
                     dataIndex: 'NOM_LOGO',
                     name: 'LOGO_PRODUIT_ASSOCIE',
                     width: 50,
                     renderer: function(value, meta) {
                         var checked = (value == 1 ? 'checked = "checked"' : '');
                         return '<input type="checkbox" value="'+value+'" '+checked+' />';
                     }
                 },{
                    header: "Nom Logo",
                    dataIndex: 'NOM_LOGO',
                    width: 300
            }]
        });
    },
PHP function : 
    private function editerLogosCommandeProduit($nocde, $codpro, $lstLogosAssocies) {
        $this->dissocierLogosProduit($nocde, $codpro);
        if (is_array($lstLogosAssocies) && (count($lstLogosAssocies) > 0)) {
            $this->associerLogosProduit($nocde, $codpro, $lstLogosAssocies);
        }
    }

Actually, those things are observed:
-> Whether I use the Ext.grid.CheckColumn Class and checboxes are displayed but not clickable
-> Whether I use the Renderer function in Ext JS which is easier to use but I don't know how to send data to PHP. Furthermore, even if I add the name porperty in the checkbox, it does not appear in the HTML Inspection in the browser.
```

Comment: I mean Checkboxes values

Comment: I would love to help but I'm a raw PHP/Javascript person and that extension makes absolutely no sense to me. Hopefully it will to some one!

From what I can tell, it looks like you are missing names on your checkboxes?
<input name='mycheckedItem1' value='1' />  At a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checkLogo = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
    dataIndex: 'CHECKED',
    editable: true,
    width: 28,
});

setCM : function(){
        this.cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            columns: [         
                checkLogo,
                {
                    header: "Nom Logo",
                    dataIndex: 'NOM_LOGO',
                    width: 300
            }]
        });
    }
```